# Retrieve Google Drive account storage quota in a Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Could someone give me an example how I can retrieve the currently used storage quota of a Google Drive account and use that information inside a Google Script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apps Script you can use `DriveApp.getStorageLimit()` to get the total storage space and `DriveApp.getStorageUsed()` to get the used storage space.

**References:**

[DriveApp | getStorageLimit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getstoragelimit)

[DriveApp | getStorageUsed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getstorageused)